# ios map- couple of line while am draw a line

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, google-maps-api-3, ios6

in my app i want to do while the user touch and move on the map i want to draw couple of line. how can i do this. am using this below code for draw a single line. 
**code:**

```
    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
          UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
          CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
          currentPoint.y -= 20;
          mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;

          lastpinpoint1.x = 170.000000;
          lastpinpoint1.y = 327.000000;

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
            CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            [imgMap drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width,drawImage.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
            //    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 1.0);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
            CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, lastpinpoint.x, lastpinpoint.y);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, lastpinpoint1.x, lastpinpoint1.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
            drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

In this above code with out this **CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, lastpinpoint1.x, lastpinpoint1.y);** this line for draw a single line. but i have added this **CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, lastpinpoint1.x, lastpinpoint1.y);** line for draw a second line. Now what am did wrong in this code. please help me. **Issue is:** while am move the finger on the map i want to draw a couple of line from different point to one current point. thanks for advance.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this answer

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];



}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];




UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self setAlpha:1.0];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x+20, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x+20, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0 , 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self setAlpha:1.0];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;

}
```

Hope it helps!!!